# C# Listview , Data type Mismatch on insertion of record

Tags: c#, database, listview, types

I want to insert some data into Database Using C#
But I get below error

> Error:Data type Mismatch when try to Execute
>   cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

```
private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       conString =Properties.Settings.Default.TransportationConnectionString;
       con.ConnectionString = conString;
       System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
       cmd1.Connection = con;
       cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [BillingGrd] ([InvoiceNo],[FromLocation],[ToLocation],[Material],[Trip],[MetricTon],[BillWeight],[Rate],[BillAmount],[GrandTotal]) Values (@InvoiceNo,@FromLocation,@ToLocation,@Material,@Trip,@MetricTon,@BillWeight,@Rate,@BillAmount,@GrandTotal)";

            for(inc=0;inc<listView1.Items.Count;inc++)
            {
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceNo", txtBilNo.Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromLocation", listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[0].Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToLocation", listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[1].Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Material", listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[2].Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Trip", listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[3].Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MetricTon", listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[4].Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillWeight", listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[5].Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[6].Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillAmount", listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[7].Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrandTotal", textBox1.Text);

              }
                 con.Open();
                 cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();//error here datatype mismatch
                 con.Close();
          }
```

Comment: Check if the data is longer then specify in database

Comment: input string was not in correct format Float.parse(txtbill.Text) when i trying

Comment: Actual My function is I m trying retrv data from count and sum query from Bill Stmnt table to listbox. It is successfuly I done but when I saving to My BillList table there is error datatype mismatch in criteria expression..

Answer (score 0):

Try This might be work for you.....
 if not Then let me know by comment

```
private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       conString =Properties.Settings.Default.TransportationConnectionString;
       con.ConnectionString = conString;
       System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
       cmd1.Connection = con;
            for(inc=0;inc<listView1.Items.Count;inc++)
            {

                cmd1.CommandText="";
        con.Open();
        cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [BillingGrd] ([InvoiceNo],[FromLocation],[ToLocation],[Material],[Trip],[MetricTon],[BillWeight],[Rate],[BillAmount],[GrandTotal]) Values ('"+txtBilNo.Text+"','"+listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[0].Text+"','"+listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[1].Text+"','"+listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[2].Text+"','"+listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[3].Text+"','"+listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[4].Text+"','"+listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[5].Text+"','"+listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[6].Text+"','"+listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[7].Text+'")";
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();//error here datatype mismatch
                con.Close();  

              }                 

          }
```

Comment: I try this also same error i recvd. i cant understand whats wrong with me. i also care of sql injection. so add parameter but where is datatype mismatch. i also chkd value of listview into label as this way and this is corrct: label7.Text = listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[0].Text;                    label14.Text = listView1.Items[inc].SubItems[7].Text;